# mkfs. any way to personalize the uuid generation?

Tags: linux, command-line, filesystems, formatting, uuid

Running `mkfs.<type> [...]` generates a File System and its UUID. any way to personalize it? In a fashion like *"not generate UUID with numbers '4' and '5' or letters 'b' 'c' "*.

Answer (score 2):

man mkfs:

```
   -U UUID
          Set the universally unique identifier (UUID) of  the  filesystem
          to UUID.  The format of the UUID is a series of hex digits sepa‐
          rated          by          hyphens,          like          this:
          "c1b9d5a2-f162-11cf-9ece-0020afc76f16".   The UUID parameter may
          also be one of the following:

               clear  clear the filesystem UUID

               random generate a new randomly-generated UUID

               time   generate a new time-based UUID
```

Comment: There is no `mkfs`. There are `mkfs.<type>`. Each of them on its own may or may not support `-U` and the option may or may not mean what you wrote. E.g. compare what `man mkfs.ntfs` says about `-U`.

Comment: It might depend on distro ? If he has a distro that isn't strict about it/ or provide mkfs.ext4 as alias to mkfs ? Which distro do you have ?